# Custom Tabbar - NavigationBar issue

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to use the tabbar with customised design , i've added the each different view to every tab item my question is i need the navigation bar with the navigation title for every tab items so here i confused with how to add that , also i faced the issue while scrolling my view which overlaps the navigation bar.

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    /// MARK: - Property Wrappers
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    @State var selectedTab: CustomTabBarVM.TabItems = .home
    
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    /// MARK: - Initializers
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    /// MARK: - View Body
    /// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                
                switch selectedTab {
                    
                case .home:
                    HomeView()
                    
                case .menu:
                    MenuView()
                    
                case .orders:
                    OrdersView()
                    
                case .cart:
                    CartView()
                    
                case .account:
                    AccountsView()
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

/// -----------------------------------------------------------------
/// MARK: - CustomTabBar View
/// -----------------------------------------------------------------

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = CustomTabBarVM()
    
    @Binding var selectedTab: CustomTabBarVM.TabItems
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                
                ForEach(CustomTabBarVM.TabItems.allCases , id: \.self) { tab in
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: selectedTab == tab ? tab.tabImageSelected : tab.tabImageUnselected)
                    
                        .scaleEffect(selectedTab == tab ? 1.50 : 1.0)
                    
                        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == tab ? .green : .gray)
                    
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                    
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.1)) {
                                selectedTab = tab
                            }
                        }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            
            .frame(width: nil , height: 60)
            .background(.white)
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .padding()
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.15) , radius: 5)
        }
    }
}
```